# php assistance with quiz results

Tags: php

I have a module that the user clicks through and watches a video.  There are progress checks throughout that are not graded but the requester now wants the user to have to retake the progress check if they didn't get all of the answers correct.  I believe the line of code for this needs to be in the next button back to progress check.  Thank you for any help!

Here is my code:

`progress results.php`

```
if ($feedback = "Correct!") {           
    echo '<a id="next" href="' . $filename . '.php?page=' . ($page) . '">Next</a>';
}
else {
    echo '<a id="next" href="progress_check.php?page=' . ($page+1) . '">Next</a>';
}
```

Comment: You should only post the _relevant_ code, not the complete app. Btw... you should also form your question as a... question. Clearify how it works now, what the issue is and what you have tried to solve it.

Comment: Side note: `if ($feedback = "Correct!")`, this sets, not compares the variable. You need `==` to compare variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, we have three kinds of "=" uses :

### Assignment operator : =

```
$var = 'Alex';
```

Here, we just asign the value of `Alex` to a variable called `$var`, we do not make any other type of operation as comparing values.

### Comparison operator : *Equal to* ==

```
$var == 'Alex';
```

Here, we check if the variable `$var` has a value ***equal to*** `Alex`. Frequently used in an *if statement* to compare two variables.

```
if ($var == 'Alex') {
    # code...
}
```

### Comparison operator : *Identical to* ===

And here, we make sure if the variables have the same values and an identical type, for example comparing a string and an integer, like this.

```
$var = '5';
if ($var === 5) {
    # code...
}
```

As you see, we are using an if statement to check if either has the same type, not just the same value, in this case, the result is `false`.

**Your case**

Try this :

```
if ($feedback == "Correct!") {
    echo '<a id="next" href="' . $filename . '.php?page=' . ($page) . '">Next</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a id="next" href="progress_check.php?page=' . ($page+1) . '">Next</a>';
}
```

More information about this topic right here : [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison)

I hope that help you to understand the behavior.

Comment: You're welcome @JanaBurgess. Please vote it up if is useful for you.